# R Loop 'for' function Boxplots; How to save emf and add tests to results matrix

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to write a for-loop producing boxplots that will be saved as emf. 
I also want correlating t.test, wilcox.test and leveneTest results to be included in a results matrix.

1. I am having problems with saving the boxplots, they do not appear in my setwd file.
2. The matrix is not completed, in fact only one value is filled in the bottom (number 26) row.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

```
##################################
setwd("C:/Users/User/Desktop/FORCEData/CaribExploration")

# Find file

CaribEx<- read.csv(file="C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\FORCEData\\CaribExploration\\CaribExplorTablecsv.csv", header=T, sep=",")
Carib <- CaribEx[3:28] # Response variables column #3:28
######################################


####Correlation loop####
#first prepare dataframe for results

X<-CaribEx$MPA #your x variable ##for you=MPA
X <- factor(X)

#Create your "results" data frame (i.e. an excel file)
#create matrix to receive results from loop [you can call M "results" if you wish]
M<-matrix(nrow=dim(Carib)[2],ncol=10)  

#Names of our results (i.e. column names in the M (results))
colnames(M)<-c("Response","Tstatistic","Tparameter","Tp.value","Mstatistic","Mparameter", "Mp.value","LDf", "LF value", "LPr(>F)")

# names  for Responses
ns<-names(Carib)

# save as emf 
emf<- function(plotname){savePlot(plotname,"emf")}
SavePlots=T


#conduct loop to compare all species in data.frame Carib vs X variable defined above
for (k in 1:dim(Carib)[2]){

  #create plot for Continuous variables column #37:50

  bp<- boxplot(Carib[,k]~ X, data= Carib, id.n=Inf, xlab="MPA", ylab= ns["Carib"] , main=ns[k], las=3,cex.axis=0.5)  
  stripchart(Carib[,k]~ X, data = Carib, vertical = TRUE, method = "jitter", ylim = c(0, 8), pch = 21, cex = 1, col=c(rgb(255, 0, 0, 100, max = 255), rgb(0, 0, 255, 100, max = 255)), bg = rgb(255, 255, 255, 10, max = 255), add = TRUE)
  test <- t.test(Carib[,k] ~ X, data = Carib)
  pvalue <- test$p.value
  pvalueformatted <- format(pvalue, digits=3, nsmall=2) #to 3 significant figures
  mtext(paste(colnames(ns[k])[2], " p = ", pvalueformatted), side=1, line=-13, at=0.9, cex = 0.6)
  print(bp)
}



Mtest <- wilcox.test(Carib[,k] ~ X, data = Carib)  #Mann Whitney test Mtest <- wilcox.test(Carib$FishRich ~ X, data = Carib)

Ltest<- leveneTest (Carib[,k] ~ X, data = Carib) # LeveneTest 

}

# add stats to matrix
print(bp1<-summary(bp)) #print the output in the file (you need the print command if using a loop, otherwise you don't see anything on the screen or file)
  # just filling the rows in the results table
  M[k,1]<-ns #insert Response
  M[k,2]<-test$statistic # store the t value
  M[k,3]<-test$parameter
  M[k,4]<-test$p.value
  M[k,5]<-Mtest$statistic
  M[k,6]<-Mtest$parameter
  M[k,7]<-Mtest$p.value
  M[k,8]<-Ltest$"LDf"
  M[k,9]<-Ltest$"F value"   
  M[k,10]<-Ltest$"Pr(>F)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are not actually calling the `emf` function anywhere. So you're not actually writing any plots to the directory. I'd imagine you want that In your `k` loop. You would want to create that right after you `print(bp)` in the loop.

And your second problem of not storing the results in the matrix is because you are assigning the values outside of the loop. Your loop ends with the `}` after the `print(bp)` line so after that point `k` is fixed at it's last value. You'll want to move that assignment into the loop as well. Basically everything should be inside the loop.

Maybe the problem is the rogue `}` after `Ltest<-` that doesn't seem to match up to an opening `{`. Not sure this code would even run as-is.